# Scala: force subclasses to override inherited implementation of a method

Tags: scala, overriding

I want to define a trait that forces its subtypes to override say the`toString` method.
Can I do that?

In the more generic case:

```
trait Old {
  def foo: String = "oldFoo"
}

trait New {
  //some statement which would result in "oldFoo" disappearing 
}

trait New1 extend New {
  def foo: String = "new1Foo"
} //should compile

trait New2 extend New //shouldn't compile
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you want to do is possible, but this workaround could work

```
trait Old {
  def foo: String = "oldFoo"
}

trait New extends Old {
  override final def foo: String = newFoo
  def newFoo: String
}

class New1 extends New {
  override def newFoo: String = "new1Foo"
} // Compiles

class New2 extends New // Don't compiles

trait NewExtra extends New // Compiles, but any sub class of NewExtra is required to implement newFoo
```

Comment: A `trait` is not required to implement inherited abstract methods, so the last line _will_ compile. If `New2` is declared a `class`, instead of a `trait`, you'll be good.

Comment: @MikeAllen Yes, you're right - thanks for point it out. I didn't noticed it because I made the example with classes but at the end I changed it to be equals to the one in the question, I will update it.